# Annotate closest OSM vertex

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to get the closest OSM vertex for each row of MyModel

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    location = GeometryField()
```

I currently use RawSQL for this

```py
def annotate_closest_vertex(queryset):
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
            closest_vertex=RawSQL(
                """
            SELECT id
            FROM planet_osm_roads_vertices_pgr
            ORDER BY the_geom <-> "mymodel"."location" LIMIT 1
            """,
                (),
            )
        )
```

And I would like to use the ORM

I tried to create a unmanaged Model for OSM vertices

```py
class OSMVertex(models.Model):
    the_geom = GeometryField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "planet_osm_roads_vertices_pgr"
```

And a distance function

```py
class Distance(Func):
    arity = 2

    def as_sql(
        self,
        compiler,
        connection,
        function=None,
        template=None,
        arg_joiner=None,
        **extra_context,
    ):
        connection.ops.check_expression_support(self)
        sql_parts = []
        params = []
        for arg in self.source_expressions:
            arg_sql, arg_params = compiler.compile(arg)
            sql_parts.append(arg_sql)
            params.extend(arg_params)
        return f"{sql_parts[0]} <-> {sql_parts[1]}", params
```

Then using a simple Subquery

```py
def annotate_closest_vertex(queryset):
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        closest_vertex=Subquery(
            OSMVertex.objects.order_by(
                Distance("the_geom", OuterRef("location"))
            ).values_list("pk")[:1]
        )
    )
```

However I get the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1324: in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:51: in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1162: in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:513: in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:55: in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:46: in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:262: in get_select
    sql, params = self.compile(col)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:445: in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py:1126: in as_sql
    subquery_sql, sql_params = query.as_sql(compiler, connection)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1103: in as_sql
    sql, params = self.get_compiler(connection=connection).as_sql()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:513: in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:56: in pre_sql_setup
    order_by = self.get_order_by()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:400: in get_order_by
    sql, params = self.compile(resolved)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:445: in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py:1218: in as_sql
    expression_sql, params = compiler.compile(self.expression)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:445: in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py:933: in as_sql
    return compiler.compile(self.expression)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:445: in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
compiler.compile call in the Distance function defined above: in as_sql
    arg_sql, arg_params = compiler.compile(arg)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:445: in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = ResolvedOuterRef(location), args = (<django.db.models.sql.compiler.SQLCompiler object at 0x7fb9f2642f70>, <django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fbbb472b5e0>), kwargs = {}

    def as_sql(self, *args, **kwargs):
>       raise ValueError(
            'This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may '
            'only be used in a subquery.'
        )
E       ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py:603: ValueError
```

I feel like the resolution of the OuterRef fails because it is located in the order_by clause.

Did someone already solved a similar issue ? I found a lot of issues related to OuterRef online but none helped me.

Comment: Is it `OuterRef` allowed in `values_list`?

Comment: Yes it is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround will be to annotate the `OuterRef` first and then use it in the order by, so try this:

```
def annotate_closest_vertex(queryset):
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        closest_vertex=Subquery(
            OSMVertex.objects.annotate(outer_location=OuterRef('location'))
            .order_by(Distance("the_geom", "outer_location"))
            .values_list("pk")[:1]
        )
    )
```

In general, you can not use `OuterRef` in the order by, but you may use it in the annotation, and then use that annotated field name in the order by.

Comment: As simple as that .. Thank you!
You state that OuterRef cannot be used in order by, could you provide some reference ?

Comment: I was unable to find any specific reference, stating that it is not possible to use OuterRef in the order by, neither in the django docs nor somewhere else. I had the same problem before and as it is all about resolution order of OuterRef, my guess was the same, the outer query was not available while resolving the order by. As it was possible to use OuterRef in the annotations and also it was possible to use annotated field in the order by, I tried that and it worked, so, that was my "guess". Probably, django could have implemented support of OuterRef in the order by, but they have not.